Iterate over Polygon vertices as Points with Shapely?
Shapely's Polygon and LinearRing are not iterable (any longer, if I remember the history correctly). I often need to iterate over their vertices as Point objects (not tuple), and my current solution seems cumbersome. Is there a simpler way than this, without NumPy magic?
poly = Polygon([Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(0, 1)])
vertices = MultiPoint(np.column_stack(poly.exterior.coords.xy))

for p in vertices.geoms:
  print(p)


Another option, if you just want to iterate the points you don't really need a MultiPoint, but an array of Points will do:
from shapely import Polygon, Point
import shapely

poly = Polygon([Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(0, 1)])
vertices = shapely.points(poly.exterior.coords)

for p in vertices:
    print(p)


The MultiPoint constructor can take an iterable of tuples, so you can do this with Polygon.exterior.coords (which returns a CoordinateSequence) and skip all the NumPy/coords.xy magic.
from shapely import Polygon, Point, MultiPoint

poly = Polygon([Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(1, 1), Point(0, 1)])
points = MultiPoint(poly.exterior.coords)

for point in points.geoms:
    print(point)

Output:
POINT (0 0)
POINT (1 0)
POINT (1 1)
POINT (0 1)
POINT (0 0)

